# WPF - Change backgroundcolor on button hover

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, hover

I tried many different options to change the backgroundcolor on hover, but it dosen't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
<Button x:Name="bAction" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,500,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="1000" BorderBrush="Black" OpacityMask="White" Background="#FF5B5B5B" IsDefault="True" Click="bAction_Click">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbAction" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Test" Foreground="White" IsEnabled="False" Width="990" Height="85" FontFamily="Letter Gothic Std" FontSize="21.333" FontWeight="Bold" TextDecorations="{x:Null}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. There's tons of tutorials and even step-by-step videos out there on how to do this.

Comment: I would look into using a style.

Comment: yep, definitely do this in the style, define the MouseOver trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try applying the below style to `Button`

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                  Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                   Value="Red" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <ContentPresenter />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```